# How to find results with name 'basketball' and 'basket' by using 'basket' in query_string?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

How to find results with name 'basketball' and 'basket' by using 'basket' in query_string? If its possible I would like as minimum changes as possible.

ES query -

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "basket",
                    "default_operator": "AND",
                    "analyze_wildcard": true
                }
                
            }
        }
    },

"size" : 50,
"from" : 0,
"sort" : {}
}
```

Mapping -

```
"name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "filename_index",
          "include_in_all": true,
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "lower_case_sort": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "naturalsort"
            }
          }
        },
```

filename_index analyzer -

```
"filename_index" : {
             "tokenizer" : "filename",
             "filter" : [
              "word_delimiter", 
              "lowercase",
              "russian_stop", 
              "russian_keywords", 
              "russian_stemmer",
              "czech_stop",
              "czech_keywords",
              "czech_stemmer"
            ]
          },
```

Elasticsearch 1.7 :(
Kind regards!

Comment: What's filename tokenizer ： "tokenizer" : "filename" ？

Comment: what was the result with [`prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html#query-dsl-prefix-query)?